# View-based NSTableView equivalent of tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

In the past, with a cell-based `NSTableView`, you could modify attributes of the cell in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row` method (for example, setting a custom `NSAttributedString` for one of the cells to display). Is there an equivalent method for view-based table view's?

Implementing `tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row` doesn't get called in a view-based table view, so I'm not sure what to do.

I want to set a `NSAttributedString` using the `setAttributedStringValue` method of the default `NSTextField` instance that is included in a `NSTableCellView` instance created from within Xcode.

My efforts so far always get undone by the table view itself. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set the class that has that method as delegate?

Comment: Yes I set the delegate correctly. That method doesn't get called when you are using a view-based table view.

Answer (score 9):

I used this to change the color of the text in `viewForTableColumn`. I am reading the tableCellView from Interface builder.

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSTableCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
    result.textField.textColor = [NSColor redColor];
    return result;
}
```

Since the textcolor actually changes for me, I believe you should be able to set other attributes there as well.

Comment: This one can be invoked far before the row is displayed (the NSTableView implementation caches row to be displayed later). So this selector is not perfectly related to display.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, NSTableViewDelegate has a few new methods:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
- (NSTableRowView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView rowViewForRow:(NSInteger)row
```

I assume that for a view-based `NSTableView`, both of these will be called. I guess you need the first one of those.

Comment: I tried setting up the properties of the `NSTextField` inside of `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` after I have created my `NSTableCellView`. However, my work gets undone by the table view after I return the `NSTableCellView` instance.

Comment: @willbur1984 I know it's an old question, but in case someone else is looking here, my guess is that the properties you're setting are reset by setBackgroundStyle. Notice how text colors depend on whether the cell is selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having a hard time with this, I think I got it working.  Oddly cellcortex's answer works using `setTextColor`, but any changes made using `setAttributedStringValue` on the built-in textField are still overwritten.  If you subclass `NSTableCellView` and make custom outlet to the `NSTextField`, you can modify the attributed string value though this outlet and not have your changes overwritten.

Here's how I did it with a view-based `NSOutlineView`:  The outline view has a column with the identifier "Detail". This column has a subclassed `NSTableCellView`  (`DBTableCellView`) with the identifier "DetailCellView".  This `DBTableCellView` has an `NSTextField` inside of it.  `DBTableCellView` has an outlet to the `NSTextField` it encompasses called "customTextField".

The outline view delegate has this method:

```
- (NSView*)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item{

  NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];

  if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Detail"]) {

    DBTableCellView * cellView = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"DetailCellView" owner:self];

    NSTextField * textField = cellView.customTextField;

    NSString * originalString = [textField stringValue];

    if (originalString.length > 0){

      [textField setAllowsEditingTextAttributes: YES];
      [textField setSelectable: YES];

      NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:originalString];

      NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSColor blueColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSSingleUnderlineStyle],NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, nil];

      NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [attrString length]);

      [attrString addAttributes:attributes range:range];

      [textField setAttributedStringValue: attrString];

    }

    return cellView;

  } else {  //specify other column identifiers here later

    return NULL;

  }

}
```

Answer (score -8):

Check the [NSTableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), you will the method you need there :

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
  willDisplayCell:(id)aCell
   forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn
              row:(NSInteger)rowIndex;
```

Comment: I may not have phrased my question very well, but I know that this is the method you use for cell-based table views. I want to know if there is some sort of similar hook for view-based table views. The above method does not get called in that case.

Comment: what is a view based table view ?

Comment: One of the new features in Lion. See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/TableViewOverview/TableViewOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH2-SW1).

Comment: that's right. I kepp learning ;) isn't @Rudy Velthuis's answer what you need ? I read the comment below, is one of these methods ever called ?

Comment: They are both called, but at some point after they are called, the table view undoes the formatting I apply to the text field. That is what has me so puzzled :(